# Call C# [WebMethod] function using an ajax call

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to call a function from a C# file in my custom module using an ajax call. I have a .js file that uses an ajax call to whitelist.aspx/isValidURL (I've also tried whitelist.cs as the file extension and url without any luck). I need to access the server method isValidURL, passing in the requested url, to see if the requested url is in a list of valid URLs. If the requested url is in the list then I want to return true to the javascript file and otherwise return false. Is this even possible? Below is the code I have thusfar:

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
    }

    if (getUrlVars()["url"].indexOf("http") > -1) {
        var urlArray = getUrlVars()["url"].split('/');
        //var protocol = urlArray[0];
        var transferurl = urlArray[2];
    } else {
        var transferurl = getUrlVars()["url"];
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "whitelist.aspx/isValidURL",
        data: {url:transferurl},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data) {
            //Redirect to the requested url because it was a valid url in the whitelist
            setTimeout(function () { window.location.assign(transferurl); }, 5000);
        } else {
            //Don't redirect to the requested url because it wasn't a valid url in the whitelist
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        //Don't redirect to the requested url because there was an error looking it up in the whitelist
    });
});
```

C# Code:

```
public class whitelist
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static bool isValidURL(string requestedURL)
        {
            //Create a list of strings to contain all the "valid" URLs
            var whiteList = new List<string>();
            //Add URLs to the list
            whiteList.Add("www.google.com");

            foreach (string validURL in whiteList)
            {
                if (requestedURL == validURL)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new ASPX page named whitelist.aspx and put your webmethod in that.
2. `stringify()` your parameters and use POST instead of GET:

   ```
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify({ requestedURL: transferurl }),
           ...
   ```
3. The return value may be wrapped, in which case you will access it as follows:

   `.done(function (data) {
       if (data.d) {
           ...
       }
   })`

Comment: Thank you so much for responding so quickly, however I am still receiving a 404(Not Fount) error. The url my ajax method is looking for is as follows: http://localhost:5551/whitelist.aspx/isValidURL I also tried the url: http://localhost:5551/whitelist.aspx but that didn't work either. Am I missing something? Do I need a controller and router to give my .aspx page a url or something? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @EmeraldArcher if you are using MVC then you can use a controller action instead of a webmethod.  I am not very fluent in MVC so if this is your scenario a google search should find you plenty of examples.:)

Comment: Thanks Slippery Pete I'll try that.